# Socket setSoTimeout clarification

Tags: java

I have scenario in which there is server listening on specified ip and port and client which connects to that server. 
Now I am reading response from server using `readline` method:

```
String readme=bs.readline()).
```

Here `bs` is `bufferedreader` object.  I want to know if before reading response if I write this line

```
socket.setSoTimeout(1000)
```

and if no response come till 1000 ms

whether socket get timeout and get disconnected or it do not disconnect socket and give empty string in `readme`.

Answer (score 5):

Actually neither.  A `SocketTimeoutException` is thrown.

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29):

> `setSoTimeout`
>
> ```
> public void setSoTimeout(int timeout)
>                   throws SocketException
> ```
>
> Enable/disable SO_TIMEOUT with the specified timeout, in milliseconds.
>   With this option set to a non-zero timeout, a read() call on the
>   InputStream associated with this Socket will block for only this
>   amount of time. If the timeout expires, a
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised, though the Socket is still
>   valid. The option **must** be enabled prior to entering the blocking
>   operation to have effect. The timeout must be > 0. A timeout of zero
>   is interpreted as an infinite timeout.
>
> **Parameters:** `timeout` - the specified timeout, in milliseconds. 
>   **Throws:**  `SocketException` - if there is an error in the underlying protocol, such as a TCP error.

Answer (score 1):

The socket will not disconnect. Instead, any reading method will throw a SocketTimeoutException that you may wish to catch in your program. The socket can still be used, but `readme` in such a case will not be defined:

```
String readme;
try
{
 readme = bs.readline;
// TODO do stuff with readme
}
catch (SocketTimeoutException e)
{
// did not receive the line. readme is undefined, but the socket can still be used
 socket.close(); // disconnect, for example
}
```

It is assumed in the example that `IOException`s are caught elsewhere or thrown.

The docs explain this behaviour quite well: [Socket.setSoTimeout(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29)

Comment: Thanks for early response. But one thing i want to clarify is that whether this type of functionality can be implemented in java(i.e readline method do not block and get timed out  and return whatever it has read till that time.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you here. The point of readLine() is to read a full line, and it might not make sense application-wise to just read whatever fragment of the line that the system retrieved so far. So it either reads the whole line or performs a timeout.

Comment: but i am asking whether this type of functionality can be implemented with using other read methods like read() etc.

Comment: The `read()` method itself follows the concept: it blocks until at least one byte of data is available ; it has reached EOF ; or when the socket does a timeout. You can see how many bytes can be retrieved without blocking using `int available()`, but this isn't very helpful in socket streams. In addition, `BufferedReader` implements `readLine()` by repeatedly performing `read()` until the line separator is found.